# Unable to log into encrypted root drive after running virtual machine

Tags: encryption, virtualization, disk-encryption, kali-linux, ubuntu

I am unable to log into my encrypted hard drive on the host which is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop. This all happened after I did the following.

1. Ran VirtualBox
2. Created a VDI drive
3. Installed Kali Linux (*When asked if I would like to encrypt the whole drive I said yes*)

After Khali was installed it went all haywire and I deleted the Kali Linux virtual machine with its files and shutdown the host as normal. This morning when I powered up the pc I was unable to use my default password to access my hosts’ hard drive.

Was there a way that Kali might have re-encrypted the drive? Because I was under the impression that it was only die 8.5 gig VDI drive that was encrypted. Is there a way that I can restore Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to a previous state before Khali was installed on the virtual machine?

Comment: Your "went haywire" could mean anything.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/880250/unable-to-log-into-encrypted-root-drive-after-running-virtual-machine